# Doxygen with C# internal access modifier

Tags: c#, doxygen

I am using Doxygen to generate some API docs for a C# project I am working on. I have quite a bit of "internal" functionality in this project and don't want Doxygen producing these signatures in the generated html it produces.

I have tried enabling HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS but this still results in my internal classes being exposed in the generated documentation.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 10):

Addon to Mac H's answer, you have to set these additional configuration parameters to make it work:

```
# The PREDEFINED tag can be used to specify one or more macro names that 
# are defined before the preprocessor is started (similar to the -D option of 
# gcc).     

PREDEFINED             = internal=private

# If the EXTRACT_PRIVATE tag is set to YES all private members of a class 
# will be included in the documentation.  

EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO

# If the ENABLE_PREPROCESSING tag is set to YES (the default) Doxygen will 
# evaluate all C-preprocessor directives found in the sources and include 
# files.

ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES

# If the MACRO_EXPANSION tag is set to YES Doxygen will expand all macro 
# names in the source code. If set to NO (the default) only conditional 
# compilation will be performed. Macro expansion can be done in a controlled 
# way by setting EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF to YES.

MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES

# If the EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF and MACRO_EXPANSION tags are both set to YES 
# then the macro expansion is limited to the macros specified with the 
# PREDEFINED and EXPAND_AS_DEFINED tags.

EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
```

Comment: **RELATED**: apparently, Doxygen won't generate a page for `public static` classes unless you set `EXTRACT_STATIC = YES`. Apparently doxygen thinks `static` means the same thing in C# that it means in C (i.e. file-private) which is extra dumb since even in C++, doxygen's native language, `static` often doesn't mean that. For some reason, without this option, such classes will still be listed (with summary) in the class list, but without a link (no class page is generated) as of v1.8.7. (P.S. wow these bugs are at least 4 years old?!)

Answer (score 5):

This is an old entry, but I had the same issue.

A method that works for me is to simply use the 'predefine' feature of doxygen. 
If you predefine 'internal=private' (which is equivalent to doing a '#define internal private') then Doxygen will see all 'internal' properties as 'private' - and so ignore them if requested.

It's a kludge -but it works.

Answer (score 1):

doxygen has several methods to exclude code from the documentation  by way of  setting options in the configuration file.

If your methods are private then set `EXTRACT_PRIVATE = NO`

You can also specify to exclude patterns, for example, if your private classes are located in a directory called  hidden,  you can exclude all files in that directory by setting.

```
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS = */hidden/*
```

Also you can avoid including non documented code by setting.

```
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES = YES
```

and

```
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS = NO
```

Comment: These are C# internal classes which are different than private classes. They have assembly scope: Only other code inside the same assembly can see them. I don't want these classes visible in the documentation, I only want public classes visible.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across the topic... use \internal doxygen keyword, it is designed just for that.

Answer (score 0):

Setting

```
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES = YES
```

works for me, even with `EXTRACT_PRIVATE` and `PREDEFINED` on default values. Not sure about the reason. I would expect they are required to be set on `NO` (so there is no documentation available for private members) and `internal=private` (so documentation is removed from internal classes as well), but that is not the case. `internal` and `private` classes are not mentioned anymore anywhere in the generated documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen apparently thinks the default for C# classes and structs is public, not internal, and will document them as such. However, **if you explicitly use the C# `internal` access modifier, Doxygen respects it** (to a degree). So, running Doxygen on this source:

```
namespace Test_Library
{
    /// <summary>
    /// I should be documented.
    /// </summary>
    public class ExplicitPublicClass
    {
        public int Field;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// I should NOT be documented.
    /// </summary>
    class ImplicitInternalClass
    {
        public int Field;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// I should NOT be documented.
    /// </summary>
    internal class ExplicitInternalClass
    {
        public int Field;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// I should be documented.
    /// </summary>
    public struct ExplicitPublicStruct
    {
        public int Field;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// I should NOT be documented.
    /// </summary>
    struct ImplicitInternalStruct
    {
        public int Field;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// I should NOT be documented.
    /// </summary>
    internal struct ExplicitInternalStruct
    {
        public int Field;
    }
}
```

gets you this Class List in Doxygen's output:

```
C ExplicitPublicClass       I should be documented.
C ExplicitPublicStruct      I should be documented.
C ImplicitInternalClass     I should NOT be documented.
C ImplicitInternalStruct    I should NOT be documented.
```

However, you do still get the explicitly internal classes and structs in Doxygen's list of classes under "Namespace Reference:"

```
class       ExplicitInternalClass
            I should NOT be documented. 

struct      ExplicitInternalStruct
            I should NOT be documented. 

class       ExplicitPublicClass
            I should be documented. More...

struct      ExplicitPublicStruct
            I should be documented. More...

class       ImplicitInternalClass
            I should NOT be documented. More...

struct      ImplicitInternalStruct
            I should NOT be documented. More...
```

But note that the "More..." link to the actual documentation (as well as the link available in the associated class/struct name) is not available for the first two.

So, you can get *some* of the behavior you are looking for by using C#'s explicit `internal` access modifier, but not necessarily *all* of the behavior you are looking for. (By way of comparison, VSDocMan processes the source code above exactly the way you want it to: only the explicitly public class and struct are documented, with no mention of either the explicitly, nor implicitly, internal classes or structs.)