# Doxygen (C#) Not Documenting Internal Classes

Tags: c#, doxygen, access-modifiers

I have internal classes in a library project. Doxygen is picking them up under the file list when the containing file is selected, but it is not showing them in the class list.

The version I'm using does not appear to have a number associated with it...

I have tried setting setting PREDEFINED = internal=private and EXTRACT_PRIVATE = yes as implied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862318/doxygen-with-c-sharp-internal-access-modifier/), and out of curiosity I've also attempted setting PREDEFINED = internal=public to no avail.

I have HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES = no, so everything should be picked up. I even have an internal class fully commented so it will be complete when internal is recognized.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same issue and fixed it by enabling (checking the box) of the following option located on the Expert tab's Build page in the Doxygen GUI front end:

```
EXTRACT_PACKAGE
```

Note that at first, I also checked all of the following (I then took them away until only `EXTRACT_PACKAGE` was left so I could provide a more definitive answer to this question, but if the above doesn't work, experiment with these):

```
EXTRACT_PRIVATE
EXTRACT_STATIC
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES
```

If needed, I'd start with `EXTRACT_PRIVATE`, as most of those are obviously unrelated to classes.

Comment: Ha, glad to help!